# Spring Oauth2 client with Google provider keep asking for authentication

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have created a Spring Oidc client application. I configure a oauth2 client like following:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: my_client_id
            client-secret: my_secret
            clientName: myapp
            redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8081/wellcome'
```

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
.... 
   @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
    }
```

redirect url is configured at http://localhost:8081/wellcome

After I initialize authentication, and client is redirected to google authentication page, it is continously asking for authentication.
If I leave default redirect url, (which is ../oauth2/code/google), application works fine.

Why redirect is not working properly if I congire a different redirect url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default redirect URI is `/login/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}`.

When redirecting to `/login/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}`, the `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter` will process the request, attempt to authenticate the user and create the `OAuth2AuthenticationToken`.

By changing the redirect URI, the `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter` is not invoked and the application does not know if the user is authenticated, which is why it prompts them to authenticate again.

You may be trying to change the `defaultSuccessUrl` instead.

This specifies where users will be redirected after authenticating successfully.

```java
http
    .oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome")
    )
```

Comment: I thought that this redirectUri from application.yml also configures the filter. This solved the problem